# How to find a missing post?

Tags: support

Earlier this month I gave a very good answer to a question about the twin paradox. Yet now I can't find the question or answer, either in my page, which supposedly lists all my answers, or by searching for questions on the twin paradox. Where is it?

Comment: It wasn't [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/327058/124), was it? If it is, and that doesn't show up in the list in your profile, could you post a screenshot of that list?

Comment: Are you sure it hasn't been deleted? (This could happen e.g. if the question was deleted.) There is a list of recently deleted answers at the bottom of [your answers list](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/89283/murray-denofsky?tab=answers) (only visible to you and ♦ moderators).

Comment: @David Z   I don't understand this advice about posting images.  
How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML? 
links, see the expanded formatting guide. Images Images can be added primarily by using the the editor toolbar button . This brings up a special interface that allows you to upload an image online … (through the imgur hosting service) through us - even from your clipboard. Alternatively, it can be input similarly to adding a link: HTML <img src="http://example.com/img.jpg"> Markdown ![sample image](http://example.com/img.jpg) …

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't understand about it, but in any case it's probably easiest to just use the image upload button. You can test it out in an empty post to see how it works. It's the sixth button from the left in the toolbar above the post editor.

Comment: Frankly, in its present form this post does not contain enough information to be answerable.

Comment: @David Z   Since I'm editing my post now, I assume I'm in the post editor. But I don't see any toolbar above it. What does the image icon look like?

Comment: @murraydenofsky [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuKPE.jpg) is the image upload button. And, again: are you sure it's not in your list of recently-deleted posts?